# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-many, integrity

I am trying to implement many to many relationship with JPA. I have 3 tables:

**Korisnik (User)** with: id, username columns.
**Tim (Team)** with: d, name, desc columns.
**Korisnik_Tim**: korisnik_id, tim_id.

Here are my entity classes:

**Korisnik class:**

```
public class Korisnik implements Serializable, AbstractModelObject {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "korisnikCollection", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Tim> timCollection;

// Getters and setters
```

Here is **Tim** class:

```
public class Tim implements Serializable, AbstractModelObject {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
@Column(name = "opis")
private String opis;
  @JoinTable(name = "tim_korisnik", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "korisnik_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "tim_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Collection<Korisnik> korisnikCollection;
```

In the front end, I am trying to add team and also add a few users to that team.

```
 public void save(){
    tim = new Tim();
    tim.setName(name);
    tim.setOpis(desc);
    tim.setKorisnikCollection(selectUsers);
    databaseBroker.save(tim);

 }
```

Here I am trying to save data to db.

```
@Override
public void save(AbstractModelObject amo) {
    try{
        em.merge(amo);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }     
}
```

Here is expcetion:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nst`.`tim_korisnik`, CONSTRAINT `fk_korisnik` FOREIGN KEY (`korisnik_id`) REFERENCES `korisnik` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO tim_korisnik (tim_id, korisnik_id) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="korisnikCollection" sql="INSERT INTO tim_korisnik (tim_id, korisnik_id) VALUES (?, ?)")
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried this also, but no effect.

```
 public void save(){
    tim = new Tim();
    tim.setName(name);
    tim.setOpis(desc);
    for(int i=0;i<selectUsers.size();i++){
        selectUsers.get(i).setTimCollection(Arrays.asList(tim));
    }
    tim.setKorisnikCollection(usersList);
    databaseBroker.save(tim);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ManyToMany assocation is bidirectional. It is the reponsability of the developper to maintain coherent both sides of the association.

Are you sure that all users in "selectUsers" have their "tim" set to the current tim ?

Morover I wouldn't set the collection but I'd prefer to add all users to the tim collection.

Also despite the CASCADE.ALL property, I'd try to persist all users before commiting the transaction.

Comment: I updated question with your suggestion, but I still get the same error. Do you have idea?

Comment: We can see in the logs that only the jointable is updated by SQL.Sometimes it's weird the order in which JPA executes SQL queries. So you also may try to create the user then flush then create the team and flush then associate both entities and commit.